# SQL - getting multiple rows into one row

Tags: mysql

I have the following situation in trying to create a datafeed from my MYSQL DB. There are more tables involved in the real situation, but I wanted to keep this brief and focused on the issue at hand.  I have two tables (products_options_values, products_options) with an intermediate table (products_options_values_to_products_options).  (Apologize for the formatting of the tables, but I think you can distinguish the values for each field.)

```
TABLE:  products_options_values<br>
products_options_values_id | products_options_values_name <br>
28 9-11<br>
52 Black<br>
53 In-Line<br>

TABLE: products_options_values_to_products_options<br>
products_options_values_to_products_options_id | products_options_id | products_options_values_id<br> 
    31  2   28<br>
    56  1   52<br>
    57  3   53<br>

TABLE: products_options<br>
products_options_id | products_options_name <br>
    1           Color<br>
    2           Size<br>
    3           Style<br>
```

I'm trying to write a SQL statement with the following results:
Fields from various TABLES about a product with products_options_name as FIELD names and corresponding products_options_values_name and corresponding values in the same row. For example:

```
Product_ID   Product_Name       MPN Price   Color   Size    Style
00001   Acme Rollerskates   A99 99.99   Black   9-11    In-Line
```

Any help on how to achieve this result in MYSQL?  Thanks for your consideration and efforts. Mark

Comment: This is what you call a `join`..table result.

Comment: Where is the products table?  Where do you store the `Product_id` and `Product_name`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the tables you provided into this format you are basically performing a *pivot* but MySQL does not have a pivot function. So you will need to replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Color' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Color,
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Size' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Size,
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Style' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Style
from products_options po
left join products_options_values_to_products_options pv
  on po.products_options_id = pv.products_options_id
left join products_options_values pov
  on pv.products_options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6922/2)

The result is:

```
| COLOR | SIZE |   STYLE |
--------------------------
| Black | 9-11 | In-Line |
```

It appears that you will still need to join in the table that contains the product details like `product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, etc.

I cannot tell from your table structure you provided where you join this data but the query would be something like this:

```
select p.product_id,
  p.product_name,
  p.MPN,
  p.price,
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Color' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Color,
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Size' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Size,
  max(case when po.products_options_name = 'Style' 
      then pov.products_options_values_name else null end) Style
from products p  --- add join to the main products table
left join products_options po
  on p.product_id = po.products_options_id
left join products_options_values_to_products_options pv
  on po.products_options_id = pv.products_options_id
left join products_options_values pov
  on pv.products_options_values_id = pov.products_options_values_id
group by p.product_id, p.product_name, p.MPN, p.price
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've heard of Magento, but this is similar to their EAV setup. Basically if you want to turn rows into columns you repeatedly have to LEFT join to the field values table once per row value. I'll do a simplified version below.

```
products table:
[id, product_name]
1, product 1
2, product 2
3, product 3

product_fields table:
[id, product_id, field_name, field_value]
1, 1, color, red
2, 2, color, blue
3, 3, color, black
4, 1, size, XL
5, 2, size, XL
6, 3, size, XL

SELECT 
    p.product_name,
    table1.field_value AS color,
    table2.field_value AS size
FROM
    products AS p LEFT JOIN product_fields AS table1 ON
        p.id = table1.product_id AND
        table1.field_name='color'
    LEFT JOIN product_fields AS table2 ON
        p.id = table2.product_id AND
        table1.field_name='size'
```

Typically the id's would be used instead of the field names in the join clause, but you should get the point. Also sql server offers a PIVOT function that might do what you need. I don't believe there is a Mysql equivalent but you could look into it.

EDIT: bluefeet's answer simulates the PIVOT function of sql server. Before 2005 that is how sql server had to do it as well. His answer was posted while I was answering.